# Iterating shift the first cell in a row ex R1C1 to left in multiple sheet excel using Rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

There is a header in my dataset at R1C1 position and I need to shift that cell to position ex R1C3.
Example- my dataframe:

```
df=data.frame(x=c("l","m",NA,NA,"p"),y=c(NA,"b","c",NA,NA),z=c("u",NA,"w","x","y"))
    df
         x    y    z
    1    l   <NA>  <NA>
    2   <NA>  <NA> <NA>
    3    a    b    c
```

I want the above dataframe converted into this:

```
      x    y    z
1    <NA> <NA>   1
2    <NA> <NA> <NA>
3    a    b     c
```

Comment: `df[1,3] <- df[1,1]` then `df[1,1] <- NA`

Comment: Thank you :) I will try this suggestion.